# class declaration with template

Tags: c++, templates

I have two classes that are defined in different ways like below:

```
template<class T, size_t N = 100> class Stack {
  T data[N];
};

template<class T = int, size_t N = 100> // Both defaulted
class Stack {
  T data[N]; 
};
```

I want to know if these are two different ways to define a class, or do they have a different meaning?

Comment: Just delete the first version of `template class Stack`, the second version works for both two occasions: `Stack<int>` and `Stack<int, 10>` are all OK.

Comment: You don't need first template version as second version of it has both default.

Answer (score 1):

The second version has a default template parameter value `int`. In other words, `T` don't necessarily needs to be specified when creating an object `Stack`.

```
Stack s; // Ok. Internal array will be 'int data[100]'.
Stack<double> s2; // Template parameter overrides default value, i.e. 'double data[100]'.
```

With the first version, the above wouldn't compile as `T` needs to be specified.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/548b536e44854328)

Comment: `Stack s;` gives this error with `clang++`: `error: use of class template 'Stack' requires template arguments`

Comment: You need the empty angle brackets (`Stack<>`).

Comment: @考えネロク No. It is not necessary.

Comment: @Snps - Pretty sure you need the empty angle brackets until C++17.  Godbolt agrees: https://godbolt.org/g/Qjqybr

Comment: @StephenNewell Well, C++17 has been published and is the current standard.

Comment: Has anyone ever thought about portability or interoperability between different compilers.  Being the current standard is only the honey we expect all to be bound.

Answer (score 1):

**Your first `Stack` class has no default value for the first template parameter:**

```
template<class T, size_t N = 100>
```

With this class, you can declare a `Stack` like this:

```
Stack<int> stack; // You have to provide at least 1 template parameter
Stack<int, 50> stack;
```

---

**Your second `Stack` class has a default value of `int` for the first template parameter:**

```
template<class T = int, size_t N = 100>
```

With this `Stack` class, you can declare a `Stack` like this:

```
Stack<> stack; // You can declare a Stack with no template parameters
Stack stack; // The same, but C++17-only
Stack<int> stack;
Stack<int, 50> stack;
```